# How to draw a line in Cesium Sandcastle between two points when one of them is moving?

Tags: javascript, reference, position, entities, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium Sandcastle to visualize my scenario of a satellite moving on his orbit.
I want to create a line between the satellite and the ground station to visualize the accesses.
The satellite is create as a variable called entity and his position is calculate with an SGP4 function, that report the variable "posizione".
The problem is that I'm not able to draw a polyline between a point that is moving and another point fixed on the earth.

I tried a few things and it didn't work, for example, following is my code:

```
function Accessi() {
var access = new Cesium.Polyline()
      show: true
      width : 1.0
      material:{
        solidColor:{
          color:{
            rgba:[
              0,255,255,255
            ]
          }
        }
      }
      positions:{
        references:[entity,observerPos
        ]
      }
};

if (lookAngles.El > 0) {
     Accessi()
};
```

the error is the following: "Expected transform to be typeof object, actual typeof was undefined"

Answer (score 0):

In order to get responsive experience with cesium, please use `CallbackProperty`. see https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Callback%20Property.html